# C++ gives me an error: no match for call to

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, static-cast

I have a problem using static_cast. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Mtx { // base matrix
private:
    // refer to derived class
    Mtx& ReferToDerived() {
        return static_cast<Mtx&>(*this);
    }
    // entry() uses features of derived class
    virtual double& entry(int i, int j){
    return ReferToDerived() (i,j);    // error appears here
    }
protected:
    int dimn; // dimension of matrix
public:
    // define common functionality in base class that can
    // be called on derived classes
    double sum() { // sum all entries
        double d = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dimn; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < dimn; j++) d += entry(i,j);
        return d;
    }
};

class FullMtx: public Mtx {
    double** mx;
public :
    FullMtx(int n) {
        dimn = n;
        mx = new double* [dimn] ;
        for (int i=0; i<dimn; i++) mx[i] = new double [dimn];
        for (int i=0; i<dimn; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<dimn; j++)
                mx[i][j] = 0; // initialization
    }
    double& operator() (int i, int j) { return mx[i] [j]; }
};

class SymmetricMtx : public Mtx {
    // store only lower triangular part to save memory
    double** mx ;
public :
    SymmetricMtx(int n) {
        dimn = n;
        mx = new double* [dimn];
        for (int i=0; i<dimn; i++) mx[i] = new double [i+1];
        for (int i=0; i<dimn; i++)
            for (int j=0; j <= i; j++)
                mx[i][j] = 0; // initialization
    }
    double& operator() (int i, int j) {
        if (i >= j ) return mx[i][j] ;
        else return mx[j][i]; // due to symmetry
    }
};

int main() 
{
    FullMtx A(1000);
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<1000; j++)
        A(i,j)=1;
    cout << "sum of full matrix A = " << A.sum() << '\n';

    SymmetricMtx S(1000); // just assign lower triangular part
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<1000; j++)
        S(i,j)=1;
    cout << "sum of symmetric matrix S = " << S.sum() << '\n';
}
```

When I run it, it says: no match for call to '(Mtx) (int&, int&)'
And I don't understand what's wrong and how should I modify it? It should be written using virtual functions, but I don't know how can I write it correctly. Can someone help me?
This program should count the sum of all the elements of the FullMatrix and SymmetricMatrix.

Comment: `return static_cast<Mtx&>(*this);` doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: why not? then how should I modify it?

Comment: @Paula It is equivalent to `return *this;`. It's not clear what you're expecting it to accomplish.

Comment: You can just use `return *this;`. The `ReferToDerived()` function name implies something like it needs a template parameter.

Comment: return *this doesn't work :(
And I need the function without templates.

Comment: You should lookup for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and consider how it could be used to solve your problem.

Comment: @Paula _"And I need the function without templates."_ Why actually?

Comment: because I am modifying the function that was with templates to one that uses virtual function. I need to see the difference between the times of execution in both

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ should I modify it somehow in a completely different way? without static_cast

Comment: @Paula _"should I modify it somehow in a completely different way?"_ You could use either dynamic (=> virtual functions) or static (=> CRTP) polymorphism.  Depends on your use case what's the better choice.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I would like to do it with dynamic polymorphism, bet I don't know how should I do it.

Comment: @Paula Introduce interfaces as abstract base classes (=> pure virtual function definitions).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so that ReferToDerived should become a pure virtual function? or do I have to declare something apart? 
I'm sorry, but I'm not too familiar with virtual functions. I am trying to get more familiar with it now...

Comment: You forgot to tell us what your program is supposed to do. We cannot magically divine that from code that, by your own admission, _does not do that thing_!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit 
sorry, I thought I did it. It's supposed to sum all elements of a matrix

Comment: In the question please.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit what do you mean?

Comment: What's confusing about what I said?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I mean that the program is supposed to sum all the elements of a matrix FullMatrix and SymmetricMatrix and the program should be written using virtual functions. 
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Please put the necessary detail _in the question_

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, the question is how should I modify it and what should become virtual, so that so that it works well?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make this any more clear. Instead of adding comments, edit your question to contain all the necessary detail.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit ups, sorry. I understood it only now and I edited it...

Answer (score 0):

remove virtual here

```
virtual double& entry(int i, int j){
    return (*this)() (i,j);    // error appears here
}
```

add virtual there

```
class Mtx {
...
    virtual double& operator() (int i, int j) = 0;
}
```

let the derived classes overload that operator and voala.

```
class FullMtx: public Mtx {
    ...
    virtual double& operator() (int i, int j) override { return mx[i] [j]; }
}
```

also this is just nonsense as already pointed out. you cast to same type, not the derived one. 
besides that you can't cast to derived type because in base you don't have the information about full inheritance - what if somebody derives from FullMtx without your knowledge ?

```
Mtx& ReferToDerived() {
    return static_cast<Mtx&>(*this);
}
```

Comment: _"and voala"_ That's a new one

Comment: I added and removed those virtual as you said. But in 
class Mtx {
...
    virtual double& operator() (int i, int j) = 0;
}
I get an errors that say: " 'virtual' outside class declaration " and
" 'double& operator()(int, int)' must be a nonstatic member function ".